# Grails and Domain Packages for Classes

Tags: grails, package

How come it is good practice within Grails to place classes in packages (e.g. mycompany.Book)?

I know it is a prerequisite in order to deploy Grails solution to the Google App Engine (using the plugin), but other than that and a well structured code library for large projects, what other benefits are there in describing packages for classes within Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good reason, as mentioned by Marcel Overdijk in [this blog post](http://marceloverdijk.blogspot.com/2009/03/grails-tip-of-day-always-use-packages.html), is if domain classes has the same name as classes within Groovy, it is not possible to distinguish the two.

Answer (score 1):

Grails runs on Groovy, which has a strong heritage with Java. Java encourages packages for well-documented reasons and Groovy/Grails follows suit. I think the main benefit stems from your description: a well-structured code library for large projects.

Answer (score 1):

The most valuable reason that I've seen, is that you cannot "import" classes without a package into a class that DOES have a package.  that means that you can't access any domain/service/controller/etc classes that don't have packages from your utility code that you might put a package on.